# SSRS 2005 in ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, reportserver

I have an instance of SSRS 2005 with its ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB in a SQL Server 2005 database.

We have to give away this SQL Server 2005 database engine and move to SQL Server 2008, as of now we do not wish to upgrade to SSRS 2008. Can I have SSRS 2005 running with ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB in SQL Server 2008 database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine, the only issue would be if you were trying to downgrade versions.