# Can SSRS 2008 be used by hosting reportserver and reportservertempdb in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2008-r2, reportserver

Can SQL Server Reporting Service 2008 be used by hosting ReportServer and ReportServerTempdb in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Not sure if this would help or not... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912274/ssrs-2005-in-reportserver-and-reportservertempdb-in-sql-server-2008?rq=1

Comment: When you install a new sql, it should come with the new reportserver. If you still want to use the old one, try change it in the Database tab in the config manager.